# recursive method - not all code paths return a value!

Tags: recursion

it says not all code paths return a value

```
private string Fisrt(string nonTerminal)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (Tokens[j, 0] == nonTerminal)
            {
                if (char.IsLower((char)Tokens[j, 3][0]))
                    return (Tokens[j, 3]);
                else
                    Fisrt(Tokens[j, 3]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's declared in the function, a string value is returned but else is not returning a string value. add a return statement to the else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string Fisrt(string nonTerminal)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (Tokens[j, 0] == nonTerminal)
            {
                if (char.IsLower((char)Tokens[j, 3][0]))
                    return (Tokens[j, 3]);
                else
                    return Fisrt(Tokens[j, 3]);
                 /* ^ add a return here */
            }
        }

        return SOMETHING;
     /* ^ You also need to add some return value here */
    }
```

You also need to decide what string value (or null) to return in the event your `for` loop exits normally.

Comment: What if `Tokens[j,0]==nonTerminal` is never true?

Answer (score 1):

For example, what if none of the `Tokens[j, 0]`,  with `j` values 0 to 5, is `nonTerminal`?

Or, if `Tokens[j, 3][0]` is never lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the recursive step

```
`return First(Tokens[j, 3])`
```

and handle the cases outside the outer `for` and `if`.